# how to have my variable read in my command

Tags: python, mysql

im trying to have a python script to search for a specific user in my database that i give it as input, and im wondering how could i get the input variable to be read in the command. here is my script
im trying to get what i input when i run the command to replace the (username) part.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Script python qui interroge la base de donnée « utilisateurs »
# Utilisation d'une requete « sql » clause « SELECT »
# Donne la liste des informations fournit par « mysql » sous forme de table formattée
# avec le module « prettytable »
#
#====================================================================================
import mysql.connector
from prettytable import PrettyTable
username = input('what user are you looking for?: ')
bd = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="P@ssword221996", database="utilisateurs")
cursor = bd.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '(username)'")
resultat = cursor.fetchall()
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["User","Filler","Uid","Gid","Gecos","Home","Login"]
x.align["User"]  = "l"
x.align["Gecos"] = "l"
x.align["Home"]  = "l"
x.align["Login"] = "l"
x.align["Uid"]   = "r"
x.align["Gid"]   = "r"
x.add_rows(resultat)
print(x)
cursor.close()
bd.close()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i forgot to say i found the answer myself

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Script python qui interroge la base de donnée « utilisateurs »
# Utilisation d'une requete « sql » clause « SELECT »
# Donne la liste des informations fournit par « mysql » sous forme de table formattée
# avec le module « prettytable »
#
#====================================================================================
import mysql.connector
from prettytable import PrettyTable
username = input('what user are you looking for?: ')
bd = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="P@ssword221996", database="utilisateurs")
cursor = bd.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE %s", [username])
resultat = cursor.fetchall()
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["User","Filler","Uid","Gid","Gecos","Home","Login"]
x.align["User"]  = "l"
x.align["Gecos"] = "l"
x.align["Home"]  = "l"
x.align["Login"] = "l"
x.align["Uid"]   = "r"
x.align["Gid"]   = "r"
x.add_rows(resultat)
print(x)
cursor.close()
bd.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `username` as a string literal in the query. Instead, you should use it as a placeholder and bind it to the query:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = %s", (username,))
```